# Curl vs Headless Chrome library C++

Tags: curl, libcurl, google-chrome-headless

Please tell me - what is the main difference between CURL/Libcurl and Headless Chrome(С++ library) for HTTPS?

1)Curl/Libcurl - implements only the HTTPS protocol (in addition to many other protocols)

2)But Headless Chrome - if I understand correctly, then, implements HTTPS protocol, processing of all HTML, css, javascript.

That is, the Headless Chrome turns out much better than Curl?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? lib curl is a library to transfer (send/receive) data in multiple protocols, one of them is http.
but the Headless Chrome is a complete Chrome web browser without renderer.
There is no complete html page parsing in libcurl.

Comment: @HojjatJafary, by better, I meant additional functions that are in Headless Chrome - that is, the functions of parsing HTML, css, JS, jquery.

Comment: you can do everything that can be done in the inspect mode of Chrome web browser using headless mode in c++, just check the examples:
https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:headless/app/headless_shell.cc

Comment: Thanks! Can you please tell me if I understand correctly that I can connect the Headless Chrome library C++ statically to my C++ project?

Comment: Seems you can do so, from its documentation:
"Headless Chromium can be built as a library for embedding into a C++ application"

Comment: Chrome is a much better Chrome than libcurl is...